# Android: Change App Background from Recent Apps

Tags: android, background

I am using below code to hide app UI when app goes to background and when we open the recent app window.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

So currently it is displaying white. How to change color to black or any desired color. Attached the screenshot
[image]